# Expresión regular para reconocer si alguien está saludando

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular como ejemplo:

```
/((hol(a|is|ap|o|as)|hello(w)?|hi|hey|saludo(s)?|(buen|buenos|buenas|buena)(\w)?(\ )?(dia(s)?|tarde(s)?|noche(s)?))(\w)?)?(\ )?(¿)?(como(\ )?(esta(s)?|te(\ )?va|te(\ )?encuentra(s)?|te(\ )?(h)?a(\ )?ido)|que (tal|onda|hay|mas))?(\w)?(\?)?/i
```

Es una expresión regular para reconocer si alguien está saludando o no, pero creo que no funciona del todo bien, ya que por ejemplo, con solo testearla con la letra `"h"` la reconoce.

Tampoco quiero agregarle el `^` al principio ni `$` al fin, ya que no puedo obligar a que se cumpla por completo el patrón, por motivos de que el lenguaje natural puede variar.

¿Cómo podría mejorarla?

Comment: No coincide con la letra `h`, sino que coincide con cualquier posición (texto vacío) porque todos los grupos son opcionales... ¿Cuál es el objetivo? ¿Coincidir con ***cualquiera*** de la palabras/frases incluidas? ¿O qué? ¿Podrías mencionar cómo la usarías?

Comment: ¿Qué saludos (y variaciones) quieres reconocer?

Comment: Te recomendariía colocar un input que "limite" la cantidad de saludos que te puede dar el usuario porque un sólo idioma tiene "n" cantidad de saludos  y para evitar estar con el problema de capturarlos todos y tener que modifcar el código "n" cantidad de veces lo mejor es "orientar" al usuario suministrándole una cantidad finita de "saludos" disponibles en tu aplicación.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, en realidad, no quiero que reconozca exacatamente los patrones que estan alli, si no que pudieran decir por ejemplo : "hola, como te esta yendo?" y que lo reconozca como saludo y que no por sola escribir por ejemplo "helena" me lo reconozca tambien como saludo por el simple hecho de tener un letra "H"

Comment: @AnthonyMedina a menos que definas un listado exacto de palabras o frases con los que debería coincidir, no vas a poder armar un regex que solucione to problema. No existe la magia en el código para que se de cuenta solo si estás saludando

Comment: creo que ya encontre la solucion

Comment: @AnthonyMedina la solución a qué? Antes que eso creo que deberías encontrar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por sus rapidas respuesta. Esta fue la solucion que encontre y me va muy bien

```
/^((hol[ai][ps]?)|h(ey|i)|hell?o|qu[eé] ?(tal|onda|hay|m[aá]s)|c[oó]mo ?(est[aá]s?|te ?(va|encuentras?))|(muy)? ?buen(os|as?)? ?(d[ií]as?|tardes?|noches?))/i
```

Comment: En tu pregunta pedías que no esté anclado a `^` ni `$`, sin embargo es lo primero que usas en esta expresión. Claramente no va a coincidir con `"¡Hola!"`. Por otro lado, estás usando demasiados grupos (paréntesis) innecesarios. Deberías intentar evitarlos. Algo como `(a|i)` es ineficiente, y conviene usar una clase de caracteres: `[ai]`. Mismo con `(s)?`, que debería ser simplemente `s?`. Además, estás escapando los espacios como en `(\ )?`, pero no hacen falta paréntesis ni la barra. Y el `[a-zA-Z0-9+]?` no tiene sentido... Deberías prestar más atención a lo que se te comentó/respondió

Comment: @Mariano menos mal que esto no es code review.
Anthony Medina: Aunque esto resuleva tu problema, sería bueno que revisaras la sección [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea útil a otras personas.

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente tu regex sigue esta forma:

```
/(a)?(b)?(c)?/
```

donde todos los grupos son opcionales y, por lo tanto, también coincide con cualquier *posición* (con cualquier texto vacío), porque no es necesario que coincida con `a`, ni con `b`, ni con `c`.

En cambio, para forzar **que coincida con al menos una de las opciones**, utilizamos un `|` ([*alternancia*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or)), que actúa como un `OR`. Un patrón para que coincida con `a`, o con `b`, o con `c` sigue la forma:

```
/a|b|c/
```

Utilizando esta forma con la lista de palabras/frases de tu expresión original, podríamos usar:

```
/hol(?:a[ps]?|is|o)|he(?:llow?|y)|hi|saludos?|buen[ao]?s? (?:d[ií]as?|tardes?|noches?)|c[oó]mo (?:est[aá]s?|te (?:va|encuentras?|h?a ido))|qu[eé] (?:tal|onda|hay|m[aá]s)/i
```

- `(?:`…`)` es un [grupo sin captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses), que actúa igual que los paréntesis simples para agrupar, pero no ocupa memoria guardando una referencia extra.

Demo:

```js
var saludo = /hol(?:a[ps]?|is|o)|he(?:llow?|y)|hi|saludos?|buen[ao]?s? (?:d[ií]as?|tardes?|noches?)|c[oó]mo (?:est[aá]s?|te (?:va|encuentras?|h?a ido))|qu[eé] (?:tal|onda|hay|m[aá]s)/i,
    resultado;

var pruebas = [
  'hola',
  'dije: ¿qué tal?',
  'hollo',
  'ella saluda diciendo buenos días',
  'yo le contesto "¿qué onda?"',
  'cómo va?',
  'Helena'
];

for (var prueba of pruebas) {
    if (resultado = saludo.exec(prueba)) {
        console.log(prueba, 'COINCIDE en la posición', resultado.index, 'CON', resultado[0]);
    } else {
        console.log(prueba, 'NO COINCIDE');
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero por ejemplo si escribes la palabra "Helena" coincide con la expresion regular y no es un saludo

Comment: @AnthonyMedina no coincide con `"Helena"`. ¿Por qué habría de coincidir? ¿Lo probaste al código?

Comment: si lo probe y me coincide con helena

Comment: @AnthonyMedina entonces hay algo mal en tu código, porque como verás, edité mi respuesta agregando `Helena` y te muestra que no coincide. Por ese motivo te pregunté si lo habías probado